# EntityFramework materializes collections not being enumerated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading

I have an entity that contains a collection of items that grows day by day. The problem is that when I do:

```
entity.Items.Add( item );
```

EF materializes the entire collection (I guess that's because I'm calling the `Items` property). This is not good, I need it only to do the insert.

Do you know if this behaviour can be changed? Thanks!

Comment: You could add the item to the Items entity set (instead of going through the navigation property) and fix the relationship from Item side.

Comment: Yes, but it breaks the design. Also, if using self-tracking-entities, EF materializes the collection anyway as it tries to update the relationship in both ends.